# Post to form in C# - pass antiforgerytoken

Tags: c#, antiforgerytoken

I'm trying to post a form trough my C# application.

My problem is that the given token is invalid and the post fails.

When I look in my browser and read the GET response it gives the correct token. I'm trying to do the same in my application but for some reason the rendered token I get is invalid.

I want to get the first actual get from the server to get the first form data. Am I doing it wrong?

```
   HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(linkToArticle);

   req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
   HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

   Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

   StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

   string rawHtml = readStream.ReadToEnd();
   string token = getToken(rawHtml);
   response.Close();
   readStream.Close();

    var loginData = new NameValueCollection();
    loginData.Add("__RequestVerificationToken", token);
    loginData.Add("cbTerms", "on");
    Console.WriteLine("token: "+ token);
    Console.WriteLine("id: "+ id);


    client.UploadValues("/Form/?aid="+id, "POST", loginData);
```

Comment: This function only parses it. What do you use to post it?

Comment: What about code that that other headers? I mean cookie part of CSRF protection...

Comment: Note that the cookie and form token values are actually different but form a matching pair that shouldn't be mixed up. You'll need to send the cookie value back as well as the form value. You don't show your getToken() function but presumably that's just parsing the form value out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need to have a cookie named **__RequestVerificationToken** with the token value. This makes sure user that posted the form was the one who displayed it.

You can read more about the process in this article:
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/

This article shows how you can achieve what you want:

http://adam.kahtava.com/journal/2009/11/25/what-are-anti-cross-site-request-forgery-tokens-and-what-are-they-good-for/